# How to determine file size in Fortran 77

Tags: fortran

I have a Fortran program that needs to read ASCII files, however the list of files sometimes includes a file of size 0. The program then crashes when trying to read this file. I have not find any way so far that will allow me to flag such a file.

I have following READ statement in my code

```
read(10,220,END=320,ERR=195)parm(1:)
```

although I expect code to go to statement 195, or to statement 320, without crashing, it crashes

this is where the code crashes when the file size is zero, with the following messages

```
...
fmt: end of file
apparent state: unit 10 named junko.con
last format: (A)
lately reading sequential formatted external IO
```

1. I tried using the INQUIRE statement
   `inquire (unit=10,SIZE=nsize)`, but the program would not compile
2. the OPEN statement did not give any error when opening the zero size file, and the values of `IOSTAT` was the same, irrespective of the file size

Comment: Please create a [mcve] for us to look at.  Here, for example, how can we be sure that the program crashes at the point you say it does?  It could be somewhere else.

Comment: It isn't an error when opening a file of zero size, so if you need to test the size of the file somehow, then please tell us how the inquire statement is failing to compile.

Comment: Please note Inquire( ..., Size = ... ) is not part of the obsolescent for over quarter of a centuryand deleted Fortran 77 standard. Rather it is part of Fortran 2003, which is good as that is what you should be using.

Answer (score 2):

As Ian noted, any modern Fortran compiler should have `INQUIRE`.  A simple test of

```
program foo
  integer sz
  inquire(file='tmp.dat',size=sz)
  print *, sz
end program foo
```

with  an empty tmp.dat file sets `sz=0`.

Comment: For a standard conforming Fortran 77 code (and I find to fathom why anyone is still using a Fortran 77 compiler), you can replace the above inquire statement with `INQUIRE(FILE='tmp.dat',RECL=SZ)`.

Comment: At least gfortran always sets RECL= to 0 or -1 if the unit is not connected, so it won't give the size of the file.

Comment: As @janneb hints, the file must be connected before `inquire(..., recl=)` returns anything potentially useful. Worse, under F77 it must be connected for direct access.  Worse still, `inquire(file=filename, recl=rl); print *, rl` (converted into F77) is actually illegal under F77 unless the file is connected appropriately.